# How can i make my Lazyrow to scroll automatically in JetpackCompose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of items and I populate them in the UI using LazyRow. Now What i want is to scroll the row automatically infinitely. But not getting any clue about it.

```
item {
                LazyRow {
                    item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp)) }
                    items(data.categories) { category ->
                        if(category.discount !=null && category.price!=null) {
                            ItemCard(
                                title = category.name,
                                imageUrl = category.image,
                                discount = category.discount,
                                price = category.price,
                                onClick = onCategoryClick
                            )
                        }
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(16.dp))
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: By "infinitely" do you mean to scroll to the last item?

Comment: Yes, but after the last item the first item will appear again and it will continue infinitely.

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is listening the visible item count in your LazyRow scroll state and remove/append half portion of your list when a specified value passed such as:

```
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()

val loadMore = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            val layoutInfo = scrollState.layoutInfo
            val totalItemsNumber = layoutInfo.totalItemsCount
            val lastVisibleItemIndex = (layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.lastOrNull()?.index ?: 0) + 1

            lastVisibleItemIndex > (totalItemsNumber - YOUR_DESIRED_NUMBER)
        }
    }

LaunchedEffect(loadMore) {
  snapshotFlow { loadMore.value }
     .distinctUntilChanged()
     .collect {
         //Remove desired count of items
         //Append the removed items to the end
     }
}

LazyRow(
    state = scrollState
) {
    items.forEach {
         item(key = item.id) { item -> //key is important here
              YourItem(item)
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I implement endless right-left scroll like this

```kotlin
val scrollState = rememberLazyListState()
var scrollDirection by remember { mutableStateOf(1) } // 1 = to right, -1 = to left

LazyRow(state = scrollState) {
    // other code
}

LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
    delay(2000)
    val needToScrollItems = YOU_DISPLAY_DATA_LIST.size - scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.size + 1
    val scrollWidth = needToScrollItems * (ITEM_WIDTH + SPACE_BETWEEN_ITEMS_WIDTH)
    while (true) {
        scrollState.animateScrollBy(
            value = scrollDirection * scrollWidth,
            animationSpec = tween(
                durationMillis = 4000 * needToScrollItems,
                easing = LinearEasing
            )
        )
        scrollDirection *= -1
    }
}
```

What's important here:

1. You need initial delay to make sure that `scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` value is initialized correctly (1 second is enough)
2. Don't forger to add `+1` to `needToScrollItems` because Compose adds `+1` to `scrollState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo` when sees a piece of list element
3. If you need a faster scroll, change `durationMillis` with lower value